# Java FX FXML and Controllers. Best Practices?

Tags: javafx, controllers, fxml

Current setup is: One main stage object--A (with GUI from FXML) and buttons. Clicking buttons on the main stage object will create objects from another class --B. B objects have different GUI FXML. In this case, is it best to create B objects each with its unique controller? Or do drive them by one controller?

Comment: For me the best practice is one FXML = one controller. Like that the different parts of your app will be nicelly separated. If one component have many FXML just do differents packages. Just my opinion

Comment: Thanks Chris, I guess I am going in the right direction. I tried to organize things in packages; FXML+Controller in one package, but Netbeans does not load FXML files if they are not in the default package where the main class is. I keep getting null pointer exception. I was able to get the java controller classes in another package... My current setup is package for the main and FXMLs, and a package for controllers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to divide your GUI into some logical custom controls using the fx:root construct.

1 FXML -> 1 root/ controller

Here's the tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm#BABDAAHE

Comment: Hi Puce, thanks for the feedback. Can you elaborate more? I am really new to programming :)

Comment: @melkhaldi I've added the link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice is to have 1 controller for each FXML file. The DataFX framework provides a flow API in the newest version (2b07 - Release 2.0 will follow in a few weeks) that do exactly what you need: http://www.javafxdata.org/overview_flow.html

Comment: Thanks Hendrick! this is what I currently doing. I wanted to confirm I am not overly populating the programming with objects unnecessarily.  I'll go through the link you post too. Thanks!